# resampling a sequence of timestamps in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a sequence of time stamps like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
dts = [datetime(2018, 12, 21, 10), datetime(2018, 12, 21, 11), datetime(2018, 12, 21, 12)]
```

They may or may not have gaps, but each timestamp represents a 1 hour period in time. I want to resample this to a sequence of 30 minutely timestamps representing 30 minute periods like so:
`[datetime(2018, 12, 21, 10, 0), datetime(2018, 12, 21, 10, 30), datetime(2018, 12, 21, 11, 0), datetime(2018, 12, 21, 11, 30), datetime(2018, 12, 21, 12, 0), datetime(2018, 12, 21, 12, 30)]`.

The closest I have been able to get is (ab)using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(dts, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(dts))
s.asfreq('30T').index
```

which gets me the following

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-21 10:00:00', '2018-12-21 10:30:00',
               '2018-12-21 11:00:00', '2018-12-21 11:30:00',
               '2018-12-21 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='30T')
```

Notice that it does not have "2018-12-21 12:30:00".

Comment: A bit of a clarification: In this case, the timestamps are hourlies and the frequency I want is 30 minutely with no gaps, but in the general case that I am trying to achieve, there may be gaps, and the source and target frequency are arbitrary.

Comment: I figured out a partial solution that takes into account gaps as well. The limitation is that this only works when going from a lower to a higher frequency.

`times = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(
                [(t, t + dt.timedelta(hours=1)) for t in sorted(dts)],
                closed='left');
newtimes = pd.interval_range(start=times.left[0],
                                 end=times.right[-1],
                                 freq='30min', closed='left');
newtimes = newtimes[[times.contains(t) for t in newtimes]].left.tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `pandas`. You can use `timedelta` to add time intervals to `datetime` objects.

You can use `map` to apply the interval to each element in `dts`, then `zip` and `list` to create a new interleavened list.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

dts = [datetime(2018, 12, 21, 10), datetime(2018, 12, 21, 11), datetime(2018, 12, 21, 12)]

new_dts = list(zip(dts, map(lambda x: x + timedelta(minutes=30), dts)))
```

Comment: This return list of tuples would you like flatten it ?

Comment: Fair enough. Edited to produce flat list

Answer (score 1):

Using `date_range`

```
pd.date_range(start=dts[0],end=dts[-1]+pd.Timedelta('30min'),freq='30min').tolist()
Out[203]: 
[Timestamp('2018-12-21 10:00:00', freq='30T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-21 10:30:00', freq='30T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-21 11:00:00', freq='30T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-21 11:30:00', freq='30T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-21 12:00:00', freq='30T'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-21 12:30:00', freq='30T')]
```